# progress 4gl:how to retrive database record that satisfies all the keywords entered by user in fill-in-field

Tags: progress-4gl

the keywords are entered by user i.e any number of keywords,it may be one or more. i take a fill-in-field for taking it as input and search that all pairs of keywords match a database record means ,i will display on a browse...but that record must satisfy the all keywords entered by user,if not satisfied means,it will display individual keyword result. thankyou sir-------the code i write is

```
::::ASSIGN ENTRYcount = (NUM-ENTRIES(hi:SCREEN-VALUE)).



     REPEAT  pos = 1 TO  ENTRYcount :
        ASSIGN keywordi = ENTRY(pos,trim(hi:SCREEN-VALUE)).
            FOR EACH db1.vehicles WHERE vehicles.ad-num MATCHES keywordi OR string(vehicles.sl-num) MATCHES keywordi
                OR vehicles.product-id MATCHES keywordi OR vehicles.product-name MATCHES keywordi OR
                string(vehicles.amount) MATCHES keywordi NO-LOCK:
            FOR EACH db2.service  WHERE db2.service.ad-num = db1.vehicles.ad-num NO-LOCK:
    /*             IF vcount EQ 0 AND scount LT 1 THEN */
    /*            DO:                                  */
                FIND ttservice WHERE  ttservice.service-num = service.service-num NO-LOCK NO-ERROR .
                IF AVAILABLE ttservice THEN 
                DO:

                END.
                ELSE
                DO:

                CREATE  ttservice  .
                ASSIGN  ttservice.ad-num = vehicles.ad-num 
                        ttservice.sl-num = vehicles.sl-num
                        ttservice.sl-id = service.sl-num
                        ttservice.product-id = vehicles.product-id
                        ttservice.service-num = service.service-num
                        ttservice.product-name =vehicles.product-name
                        ttservice.purchase-amt = vehicles.amount
                        ttservice.service-amt = service.service-amt NO-ERROR .
                END.
        END.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, even a dynamic query wouldn't suffice here, because you want to search every entry against every field. And it wouldn't work, because you're not adding wildcards -> * to the strings. You see, in Progress

```
display 'myhappyexample' matches 'happy'.
```

returns FALSE, while

```
display 'myhappyexample' matches '*happy*'.
```

will give you a TRUE state.
But the amount of OR clauses, added to the conversion of fields on the left side, would throw performance out the window. If you would still like to pursue this, take a look at this answer I posted on your other thread

stackoverflow.com/questions/30210548/progress-4gl-how-to-retrive-record-from-database-which-satisfies-multiple-keywo/30214270?noredirect=1#answer-30225957

And if you'd like to pursue a more elegant solution using dynamic queries (but you should ask the user to select the fields they want to filter, and then build a csv with those, and enter the filters in the order of the fields they want to search, look at this answer I posted:

stackoverflow.com/questions/30210548/progress-4gl-how-to-retrive-record-from-database-which-satisfies-multiple-keywo/30214270?noredirect=1#answer-30239320

In fact, I'd suggest an interface for the user to select which fields they wish to filter, then allow them to enter values they want to filter for that specific field, then use dynamic queries to build that. It would be more performance-wise efficient, in my opinion.

Anyway, let me know, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue? Is it differentiating all matches versus no matches? You might be able to add another field to the temp-table to track how many keywords have been matched. That way, on finding that the temp-table record already exists, on secondary keywords, just increment the counter if a keyword is hit again.

At the end of the querying, you can see if any of the records meet all the keywords by seeing if the count is the same as the number of keywords. Alternatively, you might choose to sort by that record as you might say that meeting more the keywords may make the entry more relevant than one that only meets a fewer of the keywords.

If you only want full matches, there might be some way of noting once through the first 2 or more keywords that only a few records have met those 2 or more keywords and check if they are going to meet the "all" keywords criteria and stop the searching of all records. I have this thought in my head but don't have time to think exactly how you would achieve that. This might help with the performance issues mentioned by above which are very valid.

Just a thought. 
HTH

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a special field, concatenating all the data (separated by e.g. spaces), indexed with a **word index**.

The word index field allows you to find very quickly a record with one or more words, using the CONTAINS operator.

The word index field (lets call it wind for "word index") can be:

- stored in the table and updated using triggers
- or created on the fly
  using a temp-table (copying all the vehicles data to a ttVehicles
  temp-table, with this special field).

The choice to store the wind in the table or to build it at runtime depends on the table number of records and performance needed.

Then a query as simple as:

```
FOR EACH vehicles WHERE vehicles.wind CONTAINS "keyword":
    ....
END.
```

would sufice, or better a dynamic query to filter all the keywords, that would result into:

```
FOR EACH vehicles WHERE vehicles.wind CONTAINS "keyword1"
                     OR vehicles.wind CONTAINS "keyword2"
                     OR vehicles.wind CONTAINS "keyword3"
                     OR ...
                     OR vehicles.wind CONTAINS "keywordn":

    ....
END.
```

This would have IMHO the best performance.